# Have there been any other women in Anakin's life or is Padmé his one and only?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

Have there been any women in Anakin's life that he's had an intimate/sexual relationship with other than Padmé? In *Episode II* when Padmé and Anakin are having a picnic in the fields of Naboo, the scene begins with Anakin asking Padmé if she's ever been in any relationships, followed by her mentioning Paulo, but Anakin is never shown answering.

Maybe just before the scene started it was really Padmé that asked Anakin, and then he turned the question back around on her? Looking for an answer in either canon or EU.

Comment: No. His love is pure, like a latter day Lancelot to his Guinevere

Comment: @Valorum That didn't end so well, either.

Answer (score 2):

Anakin's sole and abiding love is for Padmé. Why would he want any other woman when he has his [own personal angel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDh-ph8OaGo)?

> The name resonated in young Anakin’s heart and soul. He hadn’t seen
> her in a decade, not since he, along with Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon, had
> helped her in her struggle against the Trade Federation on Naboo. He
> had only been ten year s old at that time, but **from the moment he had
> first laid eyes on Padmé, young Anakin had known that she was the
> woman he would marry.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novelization))</sup></sub>

I think we can be reasonably certain that his love has sufficient purity that even *thinking* about another woman (in that way) would seem like a betrayal.